# Printing decimal using float,double in c++

Tags: c++, double, decimal

I have been trying to print decimals by storing the variables into float and double but I am not getting the desired output. what don't I understand about these data types?

Following is my code:

```
int main(){
    double s = 0;
    float r = 1 / 4;
    cout << r << endl;
    cout << pow((1 - s), 2) << endl;
    cout << (2 + s) << endl;
    cout << (1 / 4) * (pow((1 - s), 2)) * (2 + s) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
0
1
2
0
```

The first line should be 0.25 and the last should be 0.5.

Comment: Storing the value into a float or double won't help if you *compute* the value in integer arithmetic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing integer math. Integer one divided by integer four is rounded down to zero.

You need to tell the compiler that your number literals are floating point values.

```
float r = 1.0 / 4.0;
cout << r << endl;
cout << pow((1.0 - s), 2) << endl;
cout << (2.0 + s) << endl;
cout << (1.0 / 4.0) * (pow((1.0 - s), 2)) * (2.0 + s) << endl;
```